# Heat Map using a Date Range in QGIS 3.16.3

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I'm new to QGIS and I'm trying to make a Heat map with roughly 2000 data points using a date range. What I'm wanting is for the newer date to be the "hot" portion of my map. I've tried to figure this out on my own and I've given up, is this even possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please click 'edit' and update your question with more information about the structure of your data - is it a set of points with timestamps? Or just dates? Perhaps you just need to colour points on a scale from oldest to newest?

Answer (score 3):

If it's the weighting that you are trying to figure out then use this formula for the weighting, substituting "date" for your own date field:

`day(age("date", minimum("date")))`